# Play2 async when using action composition

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.0

In Play2, I understand the concepts of action composition and using Async {...} for asynchronous responses, but I've not seen an example of these approaches used together.

To be clear, say you're using action composition to ensure that a user is authenticated:

```
  def index = Authenticated { user =>
   Action { request =>
     Async {
        Ok("Hello " + user.name)      
     }
   }
  }
```

In the implementation of `Authenticated`, if we assume that this a DB is being looked up to retrieve a user, then it appears to me that this part would be a blocking call, leaving only the response within the `Action` body as non-blocking.

Can somebody explain how I can do non-blocking async I/O that encompasses the authentication part as well?

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to compose actions inside out, like so:

```
def index = Action { request =>
  Async {
    Authenticated { user =>
      Ok("Hello " + user.name)      
    }
  }
}
```

My `Authenticated` signature would then look something like:

```
def Authenticated(body: => Result): Result = {
  // authenticate, and then
  body
}
```

The downside here is that body parsing will occur before authentication, which may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can give a full example: http://pastebin.com/McHaqrFv

The essence of it is:

```
  def WithAuthentication(f: WithAuthentication => Result) = Action {
    implicit request => AsyncResult {
      // async auth logic goes here
    }
  }
```

In controllers simply:

```
  def indexAction = WithAuthentication {
    implicit request =>
      Ok(views.html.index())
  }
```

or even:

```
  def someAction = WithAuthentication {
    implicit request => Async {
      // more async logic here
    }
  }
```

It's a template-friendly solution, feel free to use it. Maybe sometimes i'll create a plugin from it. Just coded for my application, so far it seems working.